# how to count same value as one mysql?

Tags: mysql

i'm writting a program that will count the number of order everyday.
my table name is order_list

```
+---------------+----------+
| order_list_id | order_id |
+==========================+
| 1             | 1        |
+---------------+----------+
| 2             | 1        |
+---------------+----------+
| 3             | 2        |
+---------------+----------+
| 4             | 2        |
+---------------+----------+
| 5             | 2        |
+---------------+----------+
| 6             | 3        |
+---------------+----------+
```

how can i have a output 3?

Comment: Why 3? What is the logic behind it?

Comment: what is your desire result ?

Comment: in order_id there is a two order_id 1 how can i count it as one

Comment: Whether you need a count of unique values in order_id column ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand your requirements correctly, you need to use the `distinct` keyword, which will count duplicates only once.

```
select  count(distinct order_id)
from    yourTable
```

Further documentation on this functionality is available [here](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_distinct.asp)

Comment: this is exactly talking about. :) cheers

Answer (score 0):

Think you are looking for `max()` count result. Something like

```
select order_count from (
select order_id , count(*) as order_count
from order_list
group by order_id ) xxx
order by order_count desc
limit 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you would like to count the **distinct** values in the `order_id` field. You can achieve this using `count(distinct ...)`:

```
select count(distinct order_id) as no_of_orders from order_list
```

Answer (score 0):

it will give you a total count as distinct you need to add group by date for date wise

```
select count (distinct order_id) from table name
```

need to add for date wise

```
group by date(here your column name)
```

Answer (score 0):

**You need to Use DISTINCT for your expected output.**

you can try following query.

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(DISTINCT order_id) AS orderCount
FROM order_list
```

DISTINCT COUNT(*) will return a row for each unique count. What you want is COUNT(DISTINCT expression): evaluates expression for each row in a group and returns the number of unique, nonnull values.